# How do I make a two tone "Button" in Kivy?

Tags: python, button, colors, kivy

I would like to make a super simple two tone "button" in Kivy. The catch is that I do not want to add a background image.

I am sure - one would ask what have I tried myself - but I am less than a beginner, and I would not know where to start. However, I am good and copying and pasting.

Here is a picture that best describes my objective:

Edit:

I do not have 10 reputation points to post an image. However, imagine a simple button - with a diagonal line across - and the bottom has a different color than the top.

Edit (2):

[Link of the picture :)](http://i138.photobucket.com/albums/q271/bsqueeze/twotone_zpstxenabrd.png)

Thank you so much in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a working example of such a button. You can work with the canvas to create the effect you want. Here is the code:

```
import kivy
kivy.require('1.8.0')

from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.relativelayout import RelativeLayout
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.button import Label
from kivy.uix.button import ButtonBehavior
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.graphics import Triangle
from kivy.graphics import Color

Builder.load_string("""

<TwoColorsButton>:
    size_hint: None,None
    size: 250,250
    font_size: '26dp'  
    canvas.before:
        Color:
            rgba:0.5,0,0,1
        Triangle:
            points: [0,0, 0,root.size[1], root.size[0],0] 
        Color:
            rgba:0,0,0.5,1 
        Triangle:
            points: [0,root.size[1],root.size[0],root.size[1],root.size[0],0]
    text:'click me'
    on_press:print "I've been pressed"
""")

class TwoColorsButton(ButtonBehavior,Label):
    pass

class TwoColorsApp(App):
    def build(self):
        my_button = TwoColorsButton()
        return my_button

if __name__ == '__main__':
    TwoColorsApp().run()
```